# Unable to SSH into localhost on MacOS Big Sur (11.7.3) --> kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, unix, openssh, localhost, sshd

I am new to learning about SSH configuration on a Mac.

Remote login has been enabled via System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login: On

- Allow full disk access for remote users: Yes
- Allow access for: All Users

I still have been unsuccessful trying to ssh into the localhost.

```
$ ssh -vvv <username>@localhost
OpenSSH_9.5p1, OpenSSL 3.1.4 24 Oct 2023
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/<username>/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup localhost:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 5 IPV6_TCLASS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/<username>/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.5
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by ::1 port 22
$
```

When I go into /var/logs/system.log, this is what I see:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd.690C494C-FCE9-4947-80DB-3A01970C5794[29851]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

I have also tried starting/stopping the server via the command line:

```
sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd
```

When I go into /var/logs/system.log, this is what I see:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.openssh.sshd[29897]): Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

Any other ideas of where I should look?  I have read elsewhere that I should have a sshd_config file in /etc/ssh (i.e., https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461851/start-sshd-on-mac, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382825/where-to-find-sshd-logs-on-macos-sierra).

However, I don't see this file in my /etc/ssh directory.  Not sure if this makes a difference.